# How can I fix my Login Reset form?

Tags: vb.net, forms, passwords

So, I Have A Form that resets your name and password.
When i press reset it does nothing, no errors, nothing. I have included the login form's code and the reset form's code. I can login, everything is working! Just the reset does nothing.

[Picture Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5niRD.png)

(Meaning of words: (On Picture) Név - Name, Jelszó - Password, Jelenlegi - Current)

The code of my reset form:

```
Imports System.IO
Public Class Reset
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim RDR As StreamReader
    Dim RDRT As String
    RDR = New StreamReader("My.Resources.Regis")
    RDRT = RDR.ReadLine
    If TextBox1.Text = RDRT Then
        RDRT = RDR.ReadLine
        If TextBox2.Text = RDRT Then
            RDR.Close()
            Dim StreamWR As StreamWriter
            StreamWR = New StreamWriter("My.Resources.Regis")
            StreamWR.WriteLine("Name: ")
            StreamWR.WriteLine("Pass: ")
            StreamWR.WriteLine("RegisOld: ")
            StreamWR.WriteLine("NoLogin: ")
            StreamWR.Close()
            MessageBox.Show("Kérlek indítsd újra a programot!", "Sikeres Reset", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

The password/name txt file:

```
Name:
Pass:
RegisOld:
NoLogin:
```

Thank you!

Comment: you are not writing any data. `StreamWR.WriteLine("Name: ")` prints just what you see in the file: `Name:`

Comment: I know, i press the button does not shows the messagebox

Comment: If the `MessageBox` is not being shown, that suggests that the contents of `TextBox1` and `TextBox2` don't match the first two lines read from "My.Resources.Regis". Step through the program in dubug mode to see what the problem is.